# modify the height of 2-3-4 tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

like, there is a 2-3-4 tree built with a sequence 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10[image]

can these 10 keys be inserted in a different sequence in order to give a lower or higher 2-3-4 tree? Why?

Comment: whats a lower or higher tree btw

Comment: @Rico, shallower and deeper, respectively.